# Edit text in svg file

Tags: inkscape, svg

I am new to Inkscape, I want to edit the text in .svg file. Please let me know what are the steps to edit an already saved svg file..

Answer (score 6):

If the text is still editable (and you have the same font installed), and not outlines, you should be able to just click on it with the text tool. And you will see a flashing cursor inserted and ready for you to edit the text.

However, if the text is outlines, then there's no way to turn it back into editable text. You will need to delete the text, and retype new text.

[image: Editable text versus outlines]

Comment: Thank you! I realized it is not editable text and I have to retype it..

Comment: This doesn't work for me; the non-editable text is not deletable

Comment: @climatestudent If the text is not editable, then you can't delete it as you would delete a normal text object by putting your cursor in it.  You'd need to select the object using the select tool S, and then delete. If you can't physically select the objects, then they must be locked in some way.

Comment: @BillyKerr, thanks!